# iOS: UI Ideas for moving items between multi-level tableViews

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I am building an `iOS` app that allows the user to browse a `tableView`, click a cell, then navigate deeper into another `tableView` using a `navigationController`.

I have a requirement to be able to move any of those items/cells to another place in the navigation stack.  Right now my idea is, once the user selects the cells to move, to display a `modal` `tableView` that will allow the user to navigate through the same structure as before, but this time choose the location (by pressing and holding) to place those cells.

Are there any other UI ideas or clever programatic ideas that anyone might have that could be a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps take a look at how Apple's iOS Mail moves email messages between different mailboxes?

This also basically displays a modal view controller, but it flattens the hierarchy, by indenting nested items below their parent objects. You than just select the item that is the destination.

This of course only works if your hierarchy is not too deep, otherwise it's probably best to do it like you outlined it. The only thing I would perhaps recommend doing in addition, is to also have some sort of visual method (button?) to select the destination. A long press by itself might not be intuitive enough.

Comment: Yeah, I have looked to iOS Mail for direction and designed much of my concept after it.  My app is problematic because the user could go 20 levels deep if they wanted (think browsing through nested folders). I agree about having a button or other visual method to choose the destination...

Comment: Than perhaps use the cells to navigate the hierarchy and add an accessory view (button) on the right or left side that can be used to select the folder as the drop target. I'm thinking something like the disclousure button, but with a downward facing (and differently styled) arrow, or something that fits your design.

Comment: That is an interesting idea, but I just don't think it would work in my case.